# How to draw a image with alpha texture without changing the draw order

Tags: opengl, glsl

if i first draw a image with alpha channel at z depth 0.1 and after that i draw a rectangle at z depth 0.0.

The result is the following image where the transparent part of the image becomes black.

[image]

I can correct this by first drawing the rectangle and than drawing the image.

Since image is in front of the rectangle in z is their a way i can first draw the image and than draw the rectangle without having the transparent part of image becoming black.

After discarding the transparent fragments this is the result.

[image]

Comment: yes inside fragment shader `discard;` fragments that are transparent ... you do not even need blending for this. That is how sprites work

Comment: @Spektre i have discarded the fragments with alpha value 0 , i get a black outline around the image.

Comment: That means your alpha mask does not match pixel perfect  your RGB mask or the outline is intended by design ... You can mask out the black color instead of alpha :) .... for sprites and icons was common that pixel in one of the corners determined transparent color

Comment: @Spektre this is the result i get , this is a bitmap image of font using freetype.

Comment: There are several solutions to this. In the order of my preference; alpha blending, alpha to coverage, pre-multiplied alpha. `discard` only works well for binary (aliased) alpha.

Comment: Correction: [alpha to coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_to_coverage) is the only I know that works with arbitrary order. You need MSAA though

Comment: @Andreas do you have any write up for  alpha to coverage.

Comment: If memory serves me right you enable it like this: `glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE); glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_ONE)`. This assumes you have a multisample buffer in the first place (check your window creation code), and `glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)`. The first reduces samples covered proportional to alpha. The second sets the alpha for each sample to one. If that makes no sense you might want to read more on multisampling. These are advanced topics, so don't be discouraged if you find it hard to grasp.

Comment: 1. looks like a 1px problem  so a slower but foolproof solution would be to test the alpha/color of 8 neighbors too ... discard if any of them is transparent ... 2. If your text texture is single color you can ignore its color and  hardcode it instead ...

Comment: @ Andreas using  glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE); glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_ONE) on a multisample buffer has solved the issue. Thanks.